# How do you print a List in Elm?

Tags: elm

How do I convert a value of type `List` to a `String` in Elm?

Basically I'm looking for a function with the signature `a -> String` or `List -> String`.

### Example

Let's say I have a function `intAverage`:

```
intAverage l = case l of
  [] -> 0
  otherwise -> Debug.log (<<SHOW_FUNCTION>> l) (List.sum l // List.length l)
```

Here I want to inspect the list, in order to understand what's being passed to my function. `Debug.log` expects a `String` which makes me look for a function with the signature `a -> String` or `List -> String` but I have been unsuccessful in finding such a function in the Elm package docs.

Haskell has `Debug.traceShow` (which is simply an application of the function `show` on the first argument of `Debug.trace`) but I can't find the equivalent in Elm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On [Elm 0.19](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.19.md), it's been moved to [Debug.toString](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Debug#toString):

For example:

```
> Debug.toString [1,2,3]
"[1,2,3]" : String
```

Comment: The documentation for that module says it can't be using in production.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:** *This is no longer true as of Elm version 0.19. See the other answer to this question.*

The `toString` was what I was looking for, but couldn't find.

```
toString :: a -> String
```

I found it in the *Basics*-package: [toString documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Basics#toString)

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to **convert a List to a String in Elm**, in **production**, without the `Debug` library you can do:

```
yourList |> List.map String.fromInt |> String.join ", "
```

for a list of `Int`, it will print the integer values comma separated: `1, 2, 3, 4`.

Or, if you want it to be more general, not just for `Int`, you can create a reusable **utils function**:

```
listToString : (a -> String) -> String -> List a -> String
listToString convert separator list =
    "[" ++ (list |> List.map convert |> String.join separator) ++ "]"
```

with the square brackets at the ends if you like, and convert function and separator as parameters.

**Usage** with a list of `Int` would be:

```
yourList |> listToString String.fromInt ", "
```

to print `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, but you can apply it to a list of any type.

You can use it **recursively** too, to print a list of lists. For example `[ [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30] ]`. I will leave this as an exercise for the reader to figure out the function calls in this case.

---

Thanks to @glennsl for the useful suggestion down in the comments.

Comment: [`String.join separator`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/String#join) can be used instead of `List.intersperse separator` and `List.foldr (++)`

Comment: @glennsl Oh, nice, even shorter, and easier to read! Can we make it even more concise somehow? I will then edit the post to add the improvements.